# Jquery .load() function not loading html comment tag

Tags: jquery, html

Im using the .load() Jquery function, to include html tags inside another html file.
code example:

a.html:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        function loadContent() 
        { 
            $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
        } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="includedContent"></div> 
   <script>loadContent()</script> 
</body>
```

b.html:

```
<!--Include  it-->
<p> This is my include file </p>
```

When i'm open a.html in my browser and click "view source" i can NOT see

```
<!--Include  it-->
```

why is that?
I need it for tracing stuff.

If you make a simple html file:

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- Hello -->
    <p>Hello world </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Open it in a browser, click "view source". you CAN see

```
<!-- Hello -->
```

Why when we using .load() we can not see the comment???

Comment: Why do you rely on comments for tracing?

Comment: I need it for adv people for checking if the below code was operated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.load() Jquery function its a good and helpful way to include *.html files. But for this problem it dose not so helpful because the solution need to involve  "view source" functionality to can be seen the comments there.

What can be done?
SSI (server side include) solution, that need to be configured by the administrator. 
file .htaccess need to be configured to enabled apache to handled *.shtml files.
information about SSI can be found in the web.

Answer (score 1):

what browser are you using?  IE doesn't update the DOM (in the view source/developer tools view) in response to ajax requests, Chrome will if you look at the page using their developer tools

then load is working, and it's just about how you are trying to view the comments.  how the browsers handle updating their 'view source' in response to dynamic page events is browser specific, if you are relying on others to manipulate the DOM and then view page source to see the changes, you may have to rethink your strategy.

the comments should be in the div's Html:

```
<script> 
        function loadContent() 
        { 
            $("#includedContent").load("b.html", function() { alert($("#includedContent").html() }); 
        } 
    </script>
```

you may need to come up with a new scheme for displaying comments.  maybe add them to a hidden div, and allowing your `adv people` (whoever they may be) to click a button to see them.

Comment: In IE you have the F12 developerstools. When press F12 you see the IE dev. tools.

Comment: do you see `<p> This is my include file </p>` on the page iteself (not view source) after the call to load?

Comment: I know that... you can not see the comment with the developers tool also

Comment: There is still a problem.
If you insert comments in script inside b.html in the source file you can not see the comments

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `get()` instead of `load()`

According to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as <html>,
>   <title>, or <head> elements. **As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.**

Comment: get method fetch data from the server.
I want to do every thing in the client side

Comment: `load()` - This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function.  Both `get` and `load` are fetching data from the server (because that's where your resources are) and both are client-side, because jQuery is JavaScript which is pure client side language (Node.js is not the case here)